# Search data based on full description then get the items from tags

Tags: php, laravel

How to search the full text and then get the item based on model tags

Basically I have this model Item.

```
| id | name   | tags             |
|----|--------|------------------|
| 1  | test 1 | ipsum,amet,dolor |
| 2  | test 2 | myname,as        |
| 3  | test 3 | jendoe,gmail     |
```

then I query based on this text

```
$term = 'My test jendoe go lorem';
SELECT * FROM items WHERE tags LIKE '%'. $term .'%' LIMIT 0,1;
```

Then i will get the item 3. is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

Your query statement will return only 1 matched row (and there is only one matched row in your model). I modified the query statement as follows:

SELECT * FROM items WHERE tags LIKE '%$term%' LIMIT 0,1;

If you have several matched rows in your model and you would like to get all matched rows, you need to remove the LIMIT clause and modify your query statement as follows:

SELECT * FROM items WHERE tags LIKE '%$term%';

Hope that is helpful.

Comment: This will not work if the term is inside the full text. I just tried this before I post this question. If you can see my term is in full description. :(